# Not able to create iOS project in Xamarin Studio installed on OSX 10.10

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, osx-yosemite

Can't see iOS project type in Xamarin Studio installed on OSX 10.10. Xcode is installed properly on this machine (xcode 6 from app store).

And whenever I launch xamarin installer again to check whether it is installed properly or not it installs Xamarin.iOS again. No errors given. It finishes installation and ask for launch xamarin studio.

I created iOS project in VS 2012, was able to connect to MAC machine through build host but got error while building app as :

```
Failed to retrieve SDK location from server
```

So I copied project to OSX and opened it in Xamairn studio, there also it was not able to get SDK path.
Got error as

```
Xamarin.iOS not installed

The Xamarin.iOS SDK could not be detected. 
Either it has never been installed or an update of Xcode has removed the SDK. 
Please re install Xamarin.iOS.
```

Tried many times. Installed everything freshly but still problem persists.

About Xamarin shows Xamarin.iOS Not Installed. But whenever I installed Xamarin Studio, installation is completed without any errors.

Complete info: === Xamarin Studio ===

```
=== Xamarin Studio ===

Version 5.6.2 (build 5)
Installation UUID: 1918dbc6-bae4-43d9-8d1e-6c4b16b854d1
Runtime:
    Mono 3.10.0 ((detached/633e444)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

    Package version: 310000020

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 6.1 (6604)
Build 6A1052d

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Not Installed

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 4.99.0 (Trial Edition)
Android SDK: /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        1.6   (API level 4)
        2.1   (API level 7)
        2.2   (API level 8)
        2.3   (API level 10)
        3.0   (API level 11)
        3.1   (API level 12)
        3.2   (API level 13)
        4.0   (API level 14)
        4.0.3 (API level 15)
        4.1   (API level 16)
        4.2   (API level 17)
        4.3   (API level 18)
        4.4   (API level 19)
Java SDK: /usr
No Java runtime present, requesting install.

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version:

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 506020005
Git revision: 19bc3b64b70332bfab18faf9cf1ce7d3aa191b36
Build date: 2014-10-17 14:49:01-04

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.10.0
Darwin Macs-MacBook-Pro-4.local 14.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0
    Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014
    root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 10.9.5 isn't Yosemite. 10.9.x is Mavericks, 10.10.x is Yosemite.

Comment: in xamarin settings add the path for xcode. should solve your problems

Comment: Switch to Visual Studio for MAC?

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to rename the Xcode app? If you did, you need to specify the SDK location.

EDIT:
Try to manually install the latest version (as of Oct/31/2014) of [Xamarin.iOS 8.4.0.16](http://download.xamarin.com/MonoTouch/Mac/monotouch-8.4.0.16.pkg).

Comment: I installed Xcode from dmg and dragged it to Application folder. And re-installed xamarin so that it can take correct path. But it didn't. So I updated correct sdk path in xamarin. but still it is giving same error.  I also re-install everything from scratch.But getting same error

Comment: Maybe add some screenshots to give us more information? Without more to go on, you probably won't get many more responses. Have you tried contacting xamarin support directly?

Comment: I know this is a crazy question, but you do have a business (or at least indie) license for Xamarin.iOS?